# Draw string alignment in c#

Tags: c#, string, alignment, draw

```
ptStart.X += 80;

g.DrawString(Math.Round(decimal.Parse(dr["Amount"].ToString()), 0).ToString(), font, brush, ptStart);
```

through above code am getting below output.[image]

but i need right alignment.  i used also `string.Format("{0,8}")`. but it is also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a version of Graphics.DrawString that allows you to specify a StringFormat. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21kdfbzs(v=vs.110).aspx

The alignment of the StringFormat is what you need to specify:

```
StringFormat drawFormat = new StringFormat();
drawFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
```

The Rectangle argument you specify allows you to specify the area that the text is to be drawn in.